# add local jars to ivy build script

Tags: ant, ivy

I am working on an existing application that uses ivy to manage dependencies, and the source comes with `ivy.xml` and `ivysettings.xml` files. I am trying to add my own jar to the build.  What would be the easiest way to do this?

I tried adding a dependency to ivy.xml and I am not sure how to configure the repository directories. Maybe there are easy ways to do this? Any quick and dirty way will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your jars locally on your machine under your Local Ivy cache or your Shared Ivy cache. I believe it's `$HOME/.ivy2/local` and `$HOME/.ivy2/shared` and its in the same format as the `$HOME/.ivy2/cache` directory. If you use `<ivy:publish/>` Ant task to push your local jars to your local repository, they'll be accessible to all of your projects.

However, I recommend biting the bullet and doing things *...what's the technical term? oh yeah...* **The correct way**.

Go ahead and setup a project wide Ivy/Maven repository where you can fetch your local jars the same way you fetch your third party jars. This way, there is no difference between your local jars, and the third party jars you're using. No one has to think where a particular Jar is located or adjust their Ivy configuration to get one jar or another.

Download  either [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview). You can set these repositories up so that all the third-party jars and your local jars are available as if they're all stored in the same server. You can even add in other jar repositories that are not centrally located.

I recommend Loughran's book [Ant in Action](http://www.manning.com/loughran/). It has an excellent chapter on using Ivy. You can also look at my [ivy.dir](http://github.com/qazwart/ivy.dir) to see how I configure Ivy, so it's easily accessible to all of our projects.

Comment: Having to do things the "correct way" makes it hard enough to get Ivy working that nobody is willing to spend the 2 weeks it will take to reconfigure every module in a project in the way which it would have been if you had been using Ivy from the start. Sometimes one just wants a way to get something into the build system *now* so that the problem of setting it up can be broken up into multiple, smaller problems.

Comment: I am still in the midst of converting over a project to Ivy. We have 15 different base jar builds, and over 40 different projects. Even worse, someone made their own _solution_ which broke up all of the build files into eight or nine separate files and a convoluted system for finding locally built jars. If you have to get a build working with Ivy, it takes less than a day to setup Artifactory. I know, it took me less than a day. I downloaded an initial base set of jars, so I could start getting builds working. Not setting up Artifactory wouldn't have sped up implementation.

Comment: One thing I did do is setup a general [Ivy project](http://github.com/qazwart/ivy.dir). I could set this up as a Subversion external, and by simply adding this ivy.dir to your project, Ivy would be configured with the project. It made adoption a bit easier.

Comment: It took me about one whole day to reconfigure a single module in our system to have the complete dependency list required to get it to compile. I would have preferred a way to say "just use this jar for this dependency, I don't care what version it is", as it would get things working *now* and avoid a 2-week migration to get the entire build working. Essentially, it would spread the 2 weeks over the life of the project as people feel the need to update jars.

Comment: @Trejkaz My issue was actually trimming down the list of dependencies. The developers had checked in hundreds of jars they were "dependent" on. Some of these, of course, were dependencies of dependencies. I tossed in the whole damn list and got it to build the first time (only pulling in another hundred or so dependencies. What was helpful was [Tattletale](https://www.jboss.org/tattletale) which went through the entire project and found the true list of dependencies.

Comment: Regarding that, doesn't Ivy pull in more dependencies than the actual number of "dependencies"? I found it pulling in optional dependencies which weren't actually necessary to run our code and would bloat the installer if I just let all resolved jars go into it (which I wouldn't anyway. Getting off-topic now though I guess.)

Comment: You can configure the `ivy.xml` to not pull in certain jars that aren't needed using `<exclude>` sub-entities under the `<dependency>` entity. Or, you can download all of the dependencies anyway, and then in your `build.xml`, just include the ones you actually need. The only issue is building wars and ears. It doesn't matter if there are more jars than you need when you compile.

Answer (score 3):

The [filesystem resolver](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/resolver/filesystem.html) in conjunction with the [chain resolver](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/resolver/chain.html) should help you, assuming that you can modify the `ivysettings.xml` that you just inherited.